# Correctly removing Development Toolbar in Seaside

Tags: deployment, smalltalk, pharo, seaside

I use Seaside 3.0.7 on Pharo 1.3 and Pharo 1.4. In order to disable the Development Toolbar at the bottom of my Seaside applications i did execute, [as the Seaside Book says](http://book.seaside.st/book/advanced/deployment/deployment-preparing):

```
WAAdmin applicationDefaults
    removeParent: WADevelopmentConfiguration instance
```

Which does what it says - **BUT only about half of the registered applications take notice that their parent is gone**.

The other half still shows the Toolbar and the Configuration website for these applications still shows:

> Root Decoration Classes: WAToolDecoration [inherited]

and only after i click one time at Configure (Root Decoration Classes), the next screen shows

> Available: WAToolDecoration, Current: (empty)

and so i click nothing else but OK, and the Toolbar is finally gone.

Can anyone help me with this?

**Update:**

As Paul DeBruicker hinted on the mailinglist, this might be a bug related to a cache introduced in Seaside 3.0.4. I opened an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/seaside/issues/detail?id=746) in the bugtracker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a currently some kind of caching issue there. Paul DeBruicker provided a workaround:

> If you don't care about accessing the other applications you can run this:
>
> WADispatcher default handlers do: [ :each | WADispatcher default
> unregister: each ].
>
> which removes all of the applications that are installed in the image
> and then you can re-initialize your own applications so you only have
> the apps you're interested in to fix.
>
> It will be good to learn how to remove the toolbar without unregistering
> everything, but this may help in the short term.

Thereafter you can initialize the applications you care about.

Comment: I hope someone will fix the cache issue soon :) And also with the proposed workaround weird things happen. If i print WADispatcher default handlers do: [ :each | WADispatcher default unregister: each ]. i get the following: a Dictionary('examples'->a WADispatcher 'javascript'->a WADispatcher 'tools'->a WADispatcher )!! Only after i execute it a second time i get: a Dictionary(). What happens here?

Comment: Ok, the correct solution seems to be this: (from the same mailinglist thread) "Just yesterday, I fixed it to accumulate the 
entries to be removed, and then remove them after the traversal. I 
finally figured out that removing entries while doing the 
#withDescendantsDo: traversal would cause some entries to be missed."