# Seaside with Pharo 2.0/3.0 - how to set deployment mode?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, seaside

I can't find how to enable deployment mode through the tutorials. It says to do:
`WAGlobalConfiguration
setDeploymentMode` which isn't recognized,

or to do:

```
Initialize
  | app |
  app := self registerAsApplication: 'app-name'.
  app preferenceAt: #deploymentMode put: true
```

which executes, but doesn't remove the toolbars.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably using Seaside 3.0.8 (minor version number does not really matter). 
Your question is answered in the online [Seaside book](http://book.seaside.st) in the [chapter on deployment](http://book.seaside.st/book/advanced/deployment/deployment-preparing). There is no setting #deploymentMode. Instead, you can remove and configure individual elements of the development tools, remove them from a single application or remove them from all applications at once.

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at this question: [Correctly removing Development Toolbar in Seaside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075919/correctly-removing-development-toolbar-in-seaside).

I had similar problems as described by this question when i wanted to remove the development toolbars from more than one application at one and the same time.